# print count in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is a silly question but how can I print only the value of the `count` in a `df.describe()`?

This obviously doenst work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")


print(df.describe.count)
```

Comment: `df.describe().loc['count']` :you can use `loc[]`

Comment: Can't you use `DataFrame.count()` or `Series.count()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing AMCs and anky_91s comments to an answer:

You can directly use `df.count` or access the count value from the describing dataframe using `loc[]`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# simple
print(df.count())

# complicated
print(df.describe().loc['count']
```

Comment: I actually used this to print just the value of `count`... `df.describe().loc['count'][0]`

Comment: ah `df.count()[0]` would be the same.. sorry I forgot the parenthesis, edited the code.